# Can you enable suphp to follow symlinks for the docroot?

Tags: php, suphp

I'm trying to clone a website into a user's home directory and symlink from my website folder to `public_html`.

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 myuser myuser 4096 Dec  3 12:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 myuser myuser 4096 Dec  3 11:31 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Oct 22 00:48 conf/
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Dec  3 11:52 logs/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser   19 Dec  3 12:00 public_html -> mywebsite/
drwxr-xr-x 6 myuser myuser 4096 Nov 27 15:13 mywebsite/
```

suphp is throwing an Exception:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:299: Script "/home/myuser/whatever.com/public_html/index.php" resolving to "/home/myuser/whatever.com/mywebsite/index.php" not within configured docroot
```

I thought dropping this check would fix it, but it's not.

```
# cat /etc/suphp/suphp.conf  
...
;Check wheter script is within DOCUMENT_ROOT
;check_vhost_docroot=true
check_vhost_docroot=false
...
```

Is `check_vhost_docroot` what I'm actually looking for, or is there another option I should be looking at? Or is this even possible with suphp. I know this behavior works on our cpanel server, but that may be suexec instead of suphp.

Answer (score 2):

Add path to new docroot in **/etc/suphp/suphp.conf** file.

For example:

```
docroot=/usr/www:${HOME}/public_html:${HOME}/mywebsite
```